# Apache solr search 3.4 version in coldfusion 11

Tags: solr, coldfusion-11

Have an ecommerce application in coldfusion 11 which is using apache solr search feature for creating collection .
The built in solr version in it seems to be 3.4
When searching a word with space like 'console sink',it also brings result for products like console sink legs.
when the user expects to see the sink products. Hope that is fetching since the title contain the string
'console sink' along with legs. The sink products which are expected are also coming along with it,but in last pages.

Http request call format like this

http://localhost:8987/solr//select?indent=on&q="console sink"~10&start=0&rows=10&fl=*,score&wt=json

1. How can we handle to display the expected result(ie in the above case sink products instead of its parts) in top results of solr search?Any parameters to be passed?
2. Is it possible to upgrade the solr version without upgrading coldfusion version?

Comment: The Solr and CF versions should be independent and old Solr libraries should be able to talk to a new and modern version of Solr. You'll have to migrate your schema and reindex your content. For the first case; do you _only_ want exact hits? I.e. the field _only_ contains `console sink` and _nothing_ else? Or is there some kind of logic here that you want to apply (.. there usually is, where it could be `big console sink` etc.)

Comment: Hi,

http://localhost:8987/solr/<collectionname>/select?indent=on&q="console sink"~10&start=0&rows=10&sort=<colname> asc&fl=*,score&wt=json

Found that if the collection get sorted,may get the expected result. Sort parameter passed as above, but it does not
seems to make any diff if asc or desc given

Comment: What is the type of the `colname` given? If it is `text`, your results will seem rather random since it has multiple tokens. Instead, sort by a numeric value or a  `string` field. Also, since you're giving `~10`, the values can be within ten positions of each other. If you don't expect any other hits, then allowing ten other tokens between the values will not give you want you want.

Comment: The sort order was given based on sale which will be numeric. Rows 10 passed as pagination shows 10 rows at a time.
1) Will the sort be applied to whole results or the 10 current rows fetched? As of now, sort does not seems to get applied
irrespective of asc or desc sort given.
2)  Checked the solr admin interface through 'http://localhost:8987/solr/<collectionname>/admin/form.jsp.
Did not see the field to give the sort.Is that provision in admin interface of  version 3.4 ?

Comment: `sort` is applied to the whole result set to decide which documents should be returned first. Add examples of the sort order being returned. Solr 3.4 is far to old for me to remember anything about the admin interface, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Do we need to specify any additional parameter to consider the space between the search word
eg: console sink,kitchen faucet etc